# How do I implement (Brown) cluster represenations of texts from dicts as features for text classifier elegantly?

Tags: python, dictionary, scikit-learn, nlp

I'm trying to implement a version of Brown clusters for a series of review texts (SemEval 2014). I am using Owoputi et al.'s(2013) publicly available twitter clusters. They look like the following:

```
0000    ijust   1446
0000    i   17071657
0000    -i  4254
000100  iyou    41
000100  #innowayshapeorform 41
```

where the bitstring indicates the cluster and there are 1000 clusters.

I have extracted to dictionary where I have the relevant bitstring as the key and a list of the tokens as value: e.g.

`{'0000': ['ijust', 'i', '-i'], '000100': ['iyou', #innowayshapeorform] ...}`

I am just missing the part of how to one hot encode the text mapping the dictionary keys to indexes in a vector (1d array):

such that if a word occurs in the text AND the word occurs in a cluster that the value for the cluster is changed from 0 to 1.

e.g.
one_hot_vector = [0]*3

- cluster 1 (vector index = 0): ['I','me','my','mine']
- cluster 2 (vector index = 1): ['love', 'like', 'want','need']
- cluster 3 (vector index = 2): ['dogs', 'pets', 'cats', 'puppies']

text 1: I hate cats

text 1 vector representation: [1,0,1]

text 2: dogs love me

text 2 vector representation: [1,1,1]

text 3: I dream of sheep

text 3 vector representation: [1,0,0]

this example has 3 clusters - the clusters I have would be 1000 dimensions in length.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's hard to decipher your question, so let me formalize it a notch. What I understood so far:

- You want to map given string of `text` into one-dimensional array `a`.
- You have dictionary `d` that maps some `cluster` to list of `word`s.
- Each position `ix` in `a` corresponds to some `key` from dictionary `d`.
- `a[ix] == 1` if `text` contains any of `d[key]`, `== 0` otherwise.

The following solution seems elegant enough:

```py
keys = sorted(d.keys())
def text2vec(text):
    words = text.lower().split()
    return [
        int(any(
            (d[key] in word) for word in words
        )) for key in keys
    ]
```

Test example:

```py
test_text = "did ijust atealldonuts"
token = text2vec(test_text)
assert 1 == token[keys.index("ijust")]
assert 0 == token[keys.index("i")]
```

If I got it wrong, please improve your question, one-hot part specifically.

Not sure how `DictVectorizer` is going to help, because it transforms dictionaries, while you want to transform a piece of text. (Basically, `DictVectorizer` restores dataframe from it's json dump, sort of.)

Comment: Thanks for responding: your code throws an error for words = text.split().lower() - I assume because it first produces a list and .lower is a string method. I also think I have not explained clearly about the clusters, so I have amended above. I now get the following error: in <string>' requires string as left operand, not list. Not sure if your code or my implementation, but thank you for responding.

Comment: @Cheeter_P Sorry, that's silly confusion on my side, `lower` goes before `split`, I fixed it just now. Will take some time to get to your updates.

Comment: @Cheeter_P After skimming over your update it's seems like I solved it exactly. Please tell me if you had any luck with it.